# Tier Prcing not showing on Magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, tierprice

I have created a simple product and set prices like on the image is shown.

[image]

But it is not showing on the front-end side. Does the tier prices work with simple or not ? and second, why it's not showing on product pages if it's working with simple ?  I am using Magento 2.2.4.Thanks

Comment: did you try disabling the `MGS` module?

Comment: @MohitRane  Which one module?

Comment: I see in your screenshot there is module named `MGS` is enabled.

Comment: @MohitRane that is theme name.

Comment: okay, please Check that your tier price is lower than regular price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issues are using the custom theme, so the update cart template was changed.

Please check `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/tier_price.phtml` to see how tier prices are shown on product page and then fix in your theme.

[In Magento 2.2.4 Tier price of a simple product does not appear on a configurable product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235073/in-magento-2-2-4-tier-price-of-a-simple-product-does-not-appear-on-a-configurabl)

**Also Please update your tier price, its belongs to simple price not for whole qty, I check your screenshot its showing for whole qty price..**

> i mean if your product price is $20
>
> than if 2qty than set price 19.5 not for 39
>
> if 3qty than set price 19 not for 57 etc...

**i hope its work for you**

Comment: I think you are referring to configurable product tier prices.I have asked about Simple products. Either tier prices work with or not because on my side its not working.Thanks

Comment: may be something wrong with your special price is less than tier price... please verify.. i'm tested in my local with this version its working.

Comment: normal price is 20 and on 2 times qty it will be equal to 39 and 3 times will be equal 57 etc

Comment: try  with Normal price - 20 , if 2qty than set value 19.5, 3qty - 19

Comment: set price with single product not for whole qty.

Comment: i update my answer with explanation, please check.

Comment: Ok let me check .Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97191/discussion-between-anas-mansuri-and-mahmood-rehman).